# How to open file with extension .crdownload?

Tags: files

Is it possible to access content of file while it is downloading?.
I meant how to open partially downloaded file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you are trying to get out of a `*.crdownload`. It mostly contains metadata for Chrome to be able to restart the download.

You could use `strings` to read the printable character from the file like so:

```
$ strings 461304.crdownload
```

But that isn't going to tell you a lot if it is something like an image or song.

To actually restart the download, you can open it in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

In many cases,We can just remove **.crdownloaded** extension to access the file that are partially downloaded.But by this method, we cannot access the file while it is downloading .